# Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponential random variables with means $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ . What is the probability distribution of $Z=|X-Y|$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

We know that $X\sim\text{Exp}(\beta_1)$ and $Y\sim\text{Exp}(\beta_2)$ with the exponential pdf given by

$F_X(x) = \frac{1}{\beta_1}e^{-x/\beta_1}$.

My attempt was to try

$P(Z < z) = P(X < Y+z) - P(X < Y-z)$,

and got it to

$P(X < Y + z) = 1 - \frac{\beta_1 e^{-z/\beta_1}}{\beta_1 + \beta_2}$,

but couldn't work out the other probability since I got that the integral diverges. Any help moving forward is appreciated =)

Comment: $P(X < Y-z) = P(Y > X+z) = 1-P(Y<X+z)$ and you seem to know how to work that out

Comment: Here is an alternative approach: First, you calculate the distribution of $Z=X-Y$. Then you consider the distribution of $|Z|$. Here $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so the cases are symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
\on{P}_{Z}\pars{z} & \equiv \bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x/\beta_{1}} \over \beta_{1}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-y/\beta_{2}} \over \beta_{2}}\,
\delta\pars{z - \verts{x - y}}\dd y\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
{\bracks{z > 0} \over \beta_{1}\beta_{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x/\beta_{1}} 
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-y/\beta_{2}}\ \times
\\[2mm] &\
\phantom{= {\bracks{z > 0} \over \beta_{1}\beta_{2}}}\braces{\delta\pars{y - \bracks{x - z}} +
\delta\pars{y - \bracks{x + z}}}\dd y\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{\bracks{z > 0} \over \beta_{1}\beta_{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x/\beta_{1}}
\,\expo{-\pars{x - z}/\beta_{2}}\,\,\bracks{x - z > 0}\dd x
\\[2mm] &
+ \,\,{\bracks{z > 0} \over \beta_{1}\beta_{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x/\beta_{1}}
\,\expo{-\pars{x + z}/\beta_{2}}\,\,\bracks{x + z > 0}\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{\bracks{z > 0} \over \beta_{1}\beta_{2}}\expo{z/\beta_{2}}
\int_{z}^{\infty}\expo{-x/\beta}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] & +
\,\,{\bracks{z > 0} \over \beta_{1}\beta_{2}}\expo{-z/\beta_{2}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x/\beta}\,\dd x
\end{align}
where $\ds{{1 \over \beta} \equiv {1 \over \beta_{1}} +
{1 \over \beta_{2}}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
\on{P}_{Z}\pars{z} & =
{\bracks{z > 0} \over \beta_{1}\beta_{2}}
\pars{\expo{z/\beta_{2}}\beta\expo{-z/\beta} +
\expo{-z/\beta_{2}}\beta}
\\[5mm] & =
{\bracks{z > 0} \over \beta_{1} + \beta_{2}}
\bracks{\expo{-z/\beta_{1}} + \expo{-z/\beta_{2}}}
\end{align}
\begin{align} \mbox{} \\
&\bbx{\on{P}_{Z}\pars{z} =
\bracks{z > 0}
{\expo{-z/\beta_{1}} + \expo{-z/\beta_{2}} \over
\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}}} \\ &
\end{align}